# cannot see my piece on the board

Tags: java, swing, addition

My class Piece extends JPanel
The Board is set on a GridLayout.

my problem is i want to put a piece on a  x3 y3 of the board. I add it but i cannot see the piece.

this is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class Board extends JPanel{
private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(500, 500);
JPanel board;
JLabel piece;
MovePiece mp = new MovePiece(this);

public Board(){
     //set size of panel;
     this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
     this.addMouseListener(mp);
     this.addMouseMotionListener(mp);

  //create the Board
  board = new JPanel();
  board.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,7));
  board.setPreferredSize(dimension);
  board.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
  this.add(board);

  JPanel [][] square = new JPanel[7][9];

  for(int x = 0; x<7; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<9; y++){
          square[x][y] = new JPanel();
          square[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
          square[x][y].setBackground(new Color(185, 156, 107));
          board.add(square[x][y]);
     }
  }

  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath+"/pieces/blank.png");
  Piece orb =new Piece("Orb", "borb.png", "none", "none", 1, 'b', 0, 3, 7, icon);
  square[3][3].add(orb);
```

}
}

Comment: This `private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";` looks suspicious.  I doubt `src` will be available once the code is built

Comment: Why does Piece extend JPanel?  That seems like an interesting design choice.

Comment: The piece has some attritbutes like name, life, etc. I extend it to JPanel so I can add it as a component to my board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, at least, two things that stand out...

Firstly:

```
private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";
```

It's unlikely that the directory `src` will exist once the application is built.

Second:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath+"/pieces/blank.png");
```

`ImageIcon(String)` denotes that the reference resource is a file on the file system.  Based on the value of `imageFolderPath` this doesn't seem your likely intention.  Instead, it seems you are trying to use these images as embedded resources, in which case you should be using something more like...

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/pieces/blank.png"));
```

Personally, I would use `ImageIO` instead, at least this will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded...

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/pieces/blank.png"));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    // update UI
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
    // Probably show a message and exit...
}
```

Bonus issue:

Without seeing `Piece`, it's possible that you are not providing appropriate size hints or adding anything to it or using a `null` layout...or something else that we can't identify...

Comment: But your `icon` is stuck in the `try` block. However will it be accessed elsewhere? Oh no ;)

Comment: @peeskillet Shhh, you're spoiling the fun ;)